# Create a copy of npm repository in an offline network

Tags: npm, registry, couchdb

I need to replicate the entire npm repository with all the packages and make
it work in an offline network.
I already tried with someone else's .couch file but it seemed that for some packages, the tarball referenced to a different server (fullfat awt someting) and of course this doesn't work in the offline network.
I tried enumerating the whole repo and change the tarball references but it seems that I miss something as in some packages the installation fails.
Any idea what repository should I replicate to make the .couch file work out of the box?